# probability of tossing a fair coin

Tags: probability, probability-distribution

For the following two distributions, what does |X-1| mean?
The distribution of X for 0 head, 1 head, 2 heads and 3 heads in three tosses are 1/8, 3/8, 3/8 and 1/8.
What is |X-1| ?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

|X-1| is the absolute value of X-1. Then P(|X-1|=0)=P(X-1=0)=P(X=1)=3/8.
Similarly, P(|X-1|=1)=P(X-1=-1 or X-1=1)=P(X=0 or X=2)=1/8 + 3/8 = 4/8 = 1/2

Comment: I wonder what is wrong with my answer. Or, is it rather that the question somehow violates the rules of the site?